# Passing more than 1 parameter in post variable

Tags: php, post

I can only post using preset fields. So what I did was pass in two parameters, and then split them using explode function like

```
$usr=explode('_$%^_',$_POST['filename']);
```

and access values like `$usr[0]`, `$usr[1]`;

My question is that are there any drawbacks to this method I am using.

> I am using an ZOHO Remote API, and it has fixed fields that I can pass. I am trying to return the username. So I included that in the file name and split it once the file gets saved. Dirty solution but it worked.

Comment: why can you only post via preset fields? You trying to hack something?

Comment: I am using an ZOHO Remote API, and it has fixed fields that I can pass. I am trying to return the username. So I included that in the file name and split it once the file gets saved. Dirty solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option than `explode` may be to `serialize` or `json_encode` the data before posting and then `unserialize`/`json_decode` it after post. The end result is not much different but it will provide you with a couple distinct advantages:

- you will be able to have key/value pairs as opposed to having to refer to `$usr` by position.
- Provides a standard way to handle the data as opposed to an arbitrary string.

I make the assumption that since you are able to concatenate fields before post, you will be able to use the same method to encode your fields. If you are using JavaScript for this, JSON will be the more natural choice.